# Python - How to insert blank line at certain directory level when doing directory walk?

Tags: python

I know how to do a directory walk (using os.walk) and print out all files in a certain directory.  What I want to do further is to insert a blank line after the contents of a directory are printed for all directories at a certain level.  To illustrate, suppose I have these files:

```
/level1/level2a/file1.txt
/level1/level2a/level3a/file2.txt
/level1/level2a/level3b/levle4/file3.txt
/level1/level2b/file4.txt
/level1/level2b/file5.txt
```

I want to print them as:

```
/level1/level2a/file1.txt
/level1/level2a/level3a/file2.txt
/level1/level2a/level3b/levle4/file3.txt

/level1/level2b/file4.txt
/level1/level2b/file5.txt
```

Notice there is a blank line separating the listings of level2a and level2b (but no blank line between level3a and level3b).  I want the listings of each directory at level2 (i.e.e 2 levels down from root) to be separated by blanks.  How to do this in Python?

P.S. The listing will be quite large so I don't want to do this by hand.  Also, the script needs to be flexible so if requirement changes to insert blank lines at level 3 (instead of level 2) it needs to be able to handle that.

Comment: Since filepaths are just strings, you'd just need to split the filepaths on the slashes, and then match the nth level directory name and add a newline if it changes

Comment: what is your current code?

Comment: @TankorSmash - Very good idea.  If you copy your comment into an answer I will promote it to accepted status.

Comment: @Chronial - I have no code (the code to do os.walk is trivial) as I have no algorithm.  But TankorSmash just gave me one.

Comment: @ThomasNguyen Thanks! It looks like birei beat me to it though, and provides the full code to boot!

Comment: Have you tried it yourself though?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following. It checks if the `root` path has more than the number of directory levels indicated in the argument variable (hard-coded in the example). In that case save it in `d` variable and the previous different one in `prev_d`. Then `print` files in the normal way unless both variables are different, case where I will print a blank line.

Content of `script.py`:

```
import os
import sys

arg_dir_level = 4
prev_d = ''
d = ''

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):

    if root.count(os.sep) >= arg_dir_level:
        d = root.split(os.sep, arg_dir_level+1)[arg_dir_level]

    if prev_d and d and d != prev_d:
        print()

    for file in files:         
        print(os.path.abspath(root + os.sep + file))

    prev_d = d
```

Running it like:

```
python3 script.py '.'
```

Part of the output is:

```
/home/birei/python/ENV/lib/python3.3/site-packages/zope.event-4.0.2-py3.3.egg/zope/event/__init__.py
/home/birei/python/ENV/lib/python3.3/site-packages/zope.event-4.0.2-py3.3.egg/zope/event/__pycache__/tests.cpython-33.pyc
/home/birei/python/ENV/lib/python3.3/site-packages/zope.event-4.0.2-py3.3.egg/zope/event/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-33.pyc

/home/birei/python/ENV/lib/python3.3/site-packages/__pycache__/pkg_resources.cpython-33.pyc
/home/birei/python/ENV/lib/python3.3/site-packages/__pycache__/easy_install.cpython-33.pyc

/home/birei/python/ENV/lib/python3.3/site-packages/selenium-2.35.0-py3.3.egg/EGG-INFO/dependency_links.txt
/home/birei/python/ENV/lib/python3.3/site-packages/selenium-2.35.0-py3.3.egg/EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO
/home/birei/python/ENV/lib/python3.3/site-packages/selenium-2.35.0-py3.3.egg/EGG-INFO/not-zip-safe
```

As you can see, when the fourth subdirectory changes beginning from the root where I executed the script (`ENV`), it prints an additional newline. Perhaps you will need to adjust it but the idea will be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do what you want.

The basic idea is that whenever the root is at the level we want to do the separation at, we print out a line return.  We can check this by splitting the root path on `'/'` after removing any `'/'`s at the start of the path.  If there are `level` pieces, we're at the right place, and should insert a line return.

```
import os

def do_walk(directory, level=2):
    for root, _, files in os.walk(directory):
        if len(root.lstrip('/').split('/')) == level: 
            print
        for f in files: 
            print os.path.join(root, f)
```

Of course, this does insert an extra line return at the beginning.  If you don't want that, I suggest something like:

```
import os

def do_walk(directory, level=2):
    first = True
    for root, _, files in os.walk(directory):
        if len(root.lstrip('/').split('/')) == level: 
            if first:
                first = False
            else:
                print
        for f in files: 
            print os.path.join(root, f)
```